# HSQLDB - how to grant privileges?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

While trying to run SQL on HSQLDB I got this exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not
>   found: ADMIN  at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>     at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)

**EDIT:**
That's how I'm creating the `Connection` object:

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
    Connection conn = null;

    try {   
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test://localhost","sa","");         
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return conn;
}
```

**And this is the prepared statement that I made:**

```
    java.sql.PreparedStatement prSelect = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.ADMIN Where USERNAME=? AND PASSWORD=?;");
```

How can I grant privileges to the user? Currently I'm using SA user.

**EDIT 2:**
This is the schema that I built -

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.SHOW_ORDER(
    ORDER_CODE INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1),
    CLIENT_ID VARCHAR(10),
    NUMBER_OF_TICKETS INTEGER,  
    SHOW_CODE INTEGER,
    CLIENT_NAME VARCHAR(25),
    TOTAL_PRICE INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (ORDER_CODE),
);

CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.SHOW
(
    CODE INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1),
    MUSIC_TYPE INTEGER,
    NUMBER_OF_SEATS INTEGER,
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    S_DATE DATE,
    SEATS_TAKEN INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (CODE)
);
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.SYS_MUSIC_TYPE (
    CODE INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (CODE)
);
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.ADMIN
(
    USERNAME VARCHAR(25),
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME)
);
```

Comment: How are you creating the object and what's the statement that fails?

Comment: @beny23 I updated the code, please have a look

Comment: That is not the code that generates the error because there is no `prepareStatement()` call - which is what is causing the error. Show us the actual SQL statement that generates that error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added

Comment: Well thta's pretty obvious: you don't have a table named `PUBLIC.ADMIN`. If you expect one to be there and you did run the proper `create table` statement then you are probably connecting to the wrong database. Does the statement work when you run it from a SQL client?

Comment: Well I have this table, and also when i'm running it from SQL client it does gives me result

Comment: How do you create the table for the in memory DB?

Comment: @beny23 Simple using CREATE TABLE sql command

Answer (score 0):

Some of the DDL statements that would be most helpful to you are CREATE USER, CREATE ROLE, and GRANT.

This is the DDL statement to create a new user with the assigned password:

```
CREATE USER "CENASSIST" PASSWORD 'thepassword';
```

This DDL statement creates a ROLE, to which a group of permissions may be assigned.  The ROLE is then assigned to the user created above:

```
CREATE ROLE "FRONT_END";
GRANT FRONT_END TO "CENASSIST";
```

This block of DDL assigns the permissions for the FRONT_END role that was created.  The Permissions are for table access:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE Clients TO FRONT_END;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE Rotations TO FRONT_END;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE Institutions TO FRONT_END;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE Client_MRNs TO FRONT_END;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT ON TABLE Payers TO FRONT_END;
```

HSQLDB has an excellent online manual that details the DDL statements used for permissions and access control.