# HSQLDB auto update schema

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

For instance, I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer Id;
    private String value;
    private boolean check = false; // <-- HERE!
    // getters & setters

}
```

If I decide to change the `check` property's name to `validate`:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer Id;
    private String value;
    private boolean validate = false; // <--  HERE!
    // getters & setters

}
```

I had configured a hsqldb with:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" autowire="no" >
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource" />
    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:${user.home}/db/data;hsqldb.lock_file=false</prop>
            <prop key="user">sa</prop>
            <prop key="password"></prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.domain" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
</bean>

<bean name="hibernateProperties" autowire="byName" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> // <-- HERE!
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set to `update` shouldn't it update the schema if I make any change at the code?

I got this error trying to access `validate` because the schema wasn't updated:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.   Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.9.Final. jar:4.3.9.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na ]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462) ~[spring-   data-commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440) ~[spring-data -commons-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.1.  RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.  RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4. 2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE .jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MYCLAS0_.VALIDATE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionProxy.prepareStatement(ConnectionProxy.java:280) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.ConnectionJavassistProxy.prepareStatement(ConnectionJavassistProxy.java) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.2.5.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor112.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:189) ~[javamelody-core-1.57.0.jar:1.57.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:286) ~[javamelody-core-1.57.0.jar:1.57.0]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.prepareStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.   Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    ... 144 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MYCLAS0_.VALIDATE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ExpressionColumn.checkColumnsResolved(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 156 common frames omitted
```

## UPDATED:

after turn on the sql log I see this:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate (SchemaUpdate.java:261) main :HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table PUBLIC.my_class add column validate boolean not null
ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate (SchemaUpdate.java:262) main :default expression needed in statement [alter table PUBLIC.my_class add column validate boolean not null]
```

I don't know why is not adding the `default false` to the statement. In addition it's trying to add a new column instead of update it

Comment: You might want turn on logging of SQL statements in Hibernate, so that you can see what it is doing.

Answer (score 2):

because `boolean` can't be `null`, I notice that initialize at the object the `validate=false` doesn't have any effect. So I force to do it in JPA with:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
private boolean validate = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error represents you don't have enough privileges on the schema you are currently working on.

Check the below line.

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MYCLAS0_.VERIFY
```

Validate if you have update schema permission on this said schema. Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126314/hsqldb-how-to-grant-privileges) thi understand more about this.

Comment: I'm using the `sa` user

Comment: Do you have this schema.

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean. Isn't `sa` the admin user?

Comment: Yes it is, There are two three points that you need to take care of, First thing is that hsqldb is case sensitive so try to match the name of the variable with that of the name of column. Also try to shutdown you db once and run once again.

Comment: documentation says `The exception is the default SA user, which is not case-sensitive` but it isn't the problem, the connection works well. The error is shown after restart with the changes and try to access to a column that doesn't exists (because wasn't updated)

Comment: HSQLDB (or SQL in general) is **not** case sensitive. `VALIDATE` is the same column as `validate`. SQL is only case sensitive when you use quoted identifiers. `"VALIDATE"` is indeed a different column than  `"validate"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I changed word `verify` to `validate`, in my example

Comment: Validate is present in you object but check the case for it as per the suggestion from @a_horse_with_no_name